# Logging to Sentry from Celery tasks

Tags: python, logging, flask, celery, sentry

Maybe my question will seem silly, but I can't understand how to properly setup logging from celery tasks to **Sentry**.

For example, I have a module `tasks.py` with two tasks: `foo` and `bar`.
I want to get logger inside task and send all `logger.info` and `logger.error` messages directly to Sentry, not to file.

Please tell me how it is done correctly, and if you want with some simple examples.

Answer (score 1):

look at [sentry logging](http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/logging.html)

or replace logging configuration in your settings.py with the following

```
LOGGING = {
  'version': 1,
  'disable_existing_loggers': True,

'formatters': {
    'console': {
        'format': '[%(asctime)s][%(levelname)s] %(name)s %(filename)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d | %(message)s',
        'datefmt': '%H:%M:%S',
        },
    },

'handlers': {
    'console': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'console'
        },
    'sentry': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'class': 'raven.handlers.logging.SentryHandler',
        'dsn': 'http://public:secret@example.com/1',
        },
    },

'loggers': {
    '': {
        'handlers': ['console', 'sentry'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': False,
        },
    'your_app': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
   'celery': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'handlers': ['sentry'],
        'propagate': False,
    },
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did and passes my smoke test.  Place this at the top of one of your `tasks.py`

```
@setup_logging.connect
def project_setup_logging(loglevel, logfile, format, colorize, **kwargs):
    import logging.config
    from django.conf import settings
    logging.config.dictConfigClass(settings.LOGGING).configure()
```

And my relevant `settings.LOGGING`

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,

    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s",
            'datefmt': "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
    },

    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'stream': sys.stdout
        },
        'logfile': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': './django.log',
            'maxBytes': 1024*1024*5, # 5 MB
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
        'sentry': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['sentry'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'ERROR',
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['sentry'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['sentry'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'raven': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'sentry.errors': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'sentry', 'logfile'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
    }
}
```

Then my test is this..

```
@celery.task()
def dummy_logging_test(**kwargs):
    """Call this as dummy_test.delay()"""
    from .models import User

    log = dummy_logging_test.get_logger()
    if settings.DEBUG:
        log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    log.debug("Debug DUMMY TEST")
    log.info("Info DUMMY TEST")
    log.warning("Warning DUMMY TEST")
    log.error("Error DUMMY TEST")
    log.critical("Critical DUMMY TEST")

    try:
        User.objects.get(id=9999999)
    except Exception as err:
        log.exception(err)
        raise
```